# CSS HTML Minimum width and report width

Tags: html, css

I am using IE only!!.How I correct my css to not cut off the width. 
   I set a minimum width = 5000px; Also tried  margin: 0 auto
It is cutting off the very last column. Instead of 17.456.78, it stops at 17.
Also, how would I hide the browser title header.
I know this question has been asked earlier by many others. I tried different things, but the  columns get squished in my trials

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
    <div id="printReport"  style="font:100;  margin-left: 0; margin-right:0 ; margin-top:0; margin-bottom:0; display:block; white-space:nowrap;  margin: 0px auto 0px auto ;width:100%;min-width: 5000px;">
    </div>   
     body
        {
            background:#ffffff;
            color:#000000;
            font-family: rvConsolas;
        }

        @font-face
        {
            font-family: rvConsolas;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            src: url('EmConsola.eot');
            src: url('EmConsola.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype')
        }

        #rptViewer 
        {
            display: none;
            visibility: hidden;
        }

        #printReport
        {
            visibility: visible;
            font-family: rvConsolas;
            overflow: scroll ;
            height:100%;
        }

        td 
        {
            font-family: rvConsolas;
            overflow: hidden;
            font-size: 12pt;
        }

        #Page
        {
            page-break-after: always
        }
        html, body
        {
            height:100%;
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Is the report an image?

Comment: It is  a silverlight xaml page that calls Html.Page.Window.Eval(window.print()). Does this answer the question?. When it is multiple pages we build a table and combine all the pages in one and then print on it